# React. Calling multiple event handlers in onClick results in "Null" or "undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have two event handlers, one that is within the component (the child called "counter.js" and one passed by props which is the parent "container.js")

I want to pass to events onClick however I can only get one to work at a time, not both.  I've tried writing a function that would hold both events and use that onClick but then I get errors.

Both events function find if I use just one of them, but using both tends to break.  Can I get a second set of eyes of what I'm doing wrong?

In my parent component (container.js) I pass this as props:

```
    class Container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.moveCard = this.moveCard.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      id: players.id,
      totalScore: 0,
      countInfo: [],
      evilName: '',
      color: '#6E68C5',
      scoreColor: '#74D8FF',
      fontAwe: 'score-icon',
      incrementcolor: '',
      scoreNameColor: 'white',
      glow: '',
      buttonStyle: 'count-button-start'
    };

    this.incrementCountTotal = this.incrementCountTotal.bind(this);
    this.decrementCountTotal = this.decrementCountTotal.bind(this);
  }

  incrementCountTotal() {
    this.setState({
      totalScore: this.state.totalScore + 1
    });
  }

  decrementCountTotal() {
    this.setState({
      totalScore: this.state.totalScore - 1
    });
  }

  moveCard(dragIndex, hoverIndex) {
    const { cards } = this.state;
    const dragCard = cards[dragIndex];

    this.setState(
      update(this.state, {
        cards: {
          $splice: [[dragIndex, 1], [hoverIndex, 0, dragCard]]
        }
      })
    );
  }

  sortableGroupDecorator = componentBackingInstance => {
    if (componentBackingInstance) {
      let options = {
        group: 'shared'
      };
      Sortable.create(componentBackingInstance, options);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const listPlayers = players.map(player => (
      <Counter
        key={player.id}
        player={player}
        name={player.name}
        sortableGroupDecorator={this.sortableGroupDecorator}
        decrementCountTotal={this.decrementCountTotal}
        incrementCountTotal={this.incrementCountTotal}
      />
    ));
    return (
      <ContainLeft style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <ProjectTitle>Score Keeper</ProjectTitle>
        <Copy>
          A sortable list of players that with adjustable scores.  Warning, don't go negative!
        </Copy>
        <div>
          <Stats totalScore={this.state.totalScore} players={players} />
          {listPlayers}
        </div>
      </ContainLeft>
    );
  }
}

export default Container;
```

Then in my child component I want to put two events on the onClick area but they break. (currently I only have one event in the onClick but I'd like both `this.incrementCount` and `incrementCountTotal` to work onClick (the `incrementCountTotal` is from the Parent, the `this.incrementCount`is in the child component

```
class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      score: 0,
      countInfo: [],
      evilName: '',
      color: '#6E68C5',
      scoreColor: '#74D8FF',
      fontAwe: 'score-icon',
      incrementcolor: '',
      scoreNameColor: 'white',
      glow: '',
      buttonStyle: 'count-button-start'
    };

    this.incrementCount = this.incrementCount.bind(this);
    this.decrementCount = this.decrementCount.bind(this);
  }
  incrementCount() {
    console.log('pressme');
    this.incrementCountTotal;
    this.setState({
      score: this.state.score + 1
    });
    if (this.state.score < 0) {
      this.setState({ color: '#6E68C5' });
      this.setState({ scoreNameColor: 'white' });
      this.setState({ buttonStyle: 'count-button-start' });
      this.setState({ fontAwe: 'fontAwe: score-icon' });
      this.setState({ scoreColor: '#74D8FF' });
      this.setState({ evilName: '' });
    } else if (this.state.score === 9) {
      this.setState({ scoreColor: 'white' });
    } else if (this.state.score === 19) {
      this.setState({ glow: '1px 2px 5px #74D8FF' });
    }
  }

  decrementCount() {
    this.setState({
      score: this.state.score - 1
    });
    if (this.state.score < 0) {
      this.setState({ color: '#381919' });
      this.setState({ scoreNameColor: '#F79D05' });
      this.setState({ buttonStyle: 'count-button-hovering' });
      this.setState({ fontAwe: 'fontAwe: score-icon-switch' });
      this.setState({ scoreColor: '#F79D05' });
      this.setState({ evilName: 'Darth ' });
    } else if (this.state.score === -1) {
      this.setState({ glow: '1px 2px 5px red' });
    } else if (this.state.score === 11) {
      this.setState({ scoreColor: '#74D8FF' });
    } else if (this.state.score === 21) {
      this.setState({ glow: '' });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      name,
      sortableGroupDecorator,
      decrementCountTotal,
      incrementCountTotal
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="group-list" ref={sortableGroupDecorator}>
        <CountCell style={{ background: this.state.color }}>
          <Row style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Col>
              <CountButton
                className={this.state.buttonStyle}
                onClick={this.incrementCount}
              >
                <Icon
                  name="icon"
                  className={'fa fa-plus ' + this.state.fontAwe}
                />
              </CountButton>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <ScoreName style={{ color: this.state.scoreNameColor }}>
                {this.state.evilName + name}
              </ScoreName>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <Score
                style={{
                  color: this.state.scoreColor,
                  textShadow: this.state.glow
                }}
              >
                {this.state.score}
              </Score>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <CountButton
                className={this.state.buttonStyle}
                onClick={this.decrementCount}
              >
                <Icon
                  name="icon"
                  className={'fa fa-minus ' + this.state.fontAwe}
                />
              </CountButton>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </CountCell>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Counter.propTypes = {
  player: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Counter;
```

so when I add:

`onClick={(this.incrementCount, incrementCountTotal)}` only `incrementCountTotal` works (the second argument)

If I write it inline with a function like this

```
onClick={event => {
  this.incrementCount;
  incrementCountTotal;
}}
```

Nothing works.

If I write a function to handle both it gives me undefined

```
  onClick(event) {
    incrementCountTotal, incrementCount;
  }
```

and put `onClick={this.onClick}` I get:

```
./src/components/pages/projectpages/dnd2/Counter.js
  Line 97:  'incrementCountTotal' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 97:  'incrementCount' is not defined       no-undef
```

Comment: can you include the error?

Comment: updated my question with the errors at the bottom

Comment: updated one more time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the child component, seems like you just need to call the functions (add parentheses).  Also, the incrementCountTotal is a prop, so call it this way:

```
  onClick={event => {
    this.incrementCount();
    this.props.incrementCountTotal();
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot tell you how much I appreciate you answering this for me